# Create object with different colors

Tags: objects

I'm making a jar of jelly beans and I want each jellybean to have a material with a unique color so I can drop them in the jar using a rigid body.

So far I've managed to get this to produce a bunch of new blank materials.

I figured I'd start with all the red ones. I'm a bit new to Blender/Python.

```
x = 0

for x in range(255):

    # create material, assign
    activeObject = bpy.context.active_object #Set active object to variable
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Material") #set new material to variable
    bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (x, 0, 0, 0) #change color
    activeObject.data.materials.append(mat) #add the material to the object

    x = x+1/255
```

Right now I'm just trying to create the different colored materials, and all the meshes for the jellybeans are the same.

Comment: Hello! So you'd like to create a bunch of objects and every object should have their own differently colored material? Or do you want to add a bunch of differently colored materials to a single object ?

Comment: Ideally, I would create a bunch of objects and every object would have its own different colored material. Thanks for the reply @Gorgious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*** UPDATE II ****

```
import bpy 
import random
 
def createRandomMat(object):
    
    newMat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = 'Material')
    object.data.materials.append(newMat)

    newMat.use_nodes = True

    nodes = newMat.node_tree.nodes

    material_output = nodes.get("Material Output")

    node_emission = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')

    node_emission.inputs[0].default_value = (random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),1) 

    links = newMat.node_tree.links

    newLink = links.new(node_emission.outputs[0], material_output.inputs[0])
    
   

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        location = (x*4, y*4, 0)
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location = location, scale = (1, 1, 1))
        
        object = bpy.context.active_object
        
        createRandomMat(object)
```

result:
[image]

**** UPDATE *****

you can create a random material with this function:

```
def createRandomMat(object):
    
    newMat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = 'Material')
    object.data.materials.append(newMat)

    newMat.use_nodes = True

    nodes = newMat.node_tree.nodes

    material_output = nodes.get("Material Output")

    node_emission = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')

    node_emission.inputs[0].default_value = (random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),1) 

    links = newMat.node_tree.links

    newLink = links.new(node_emission.outputs[0], material_output.inputs[0])
```

*** Classic solution ***

This very easy node setup gives you "random" colors, which you can even "self-define" by the colorramp.

[image]

[image]

or other alternative:

[image]

Comment: Hey @chris, thanks for the reply. Would each of these cubes be their own mesh/object with their own material? Or is there a way to separate them into objects and materials?

Comment: Cubes have own mesh object, but material would be the same. Why do you want extra materials? Do you want to animate the materials differently? Or why?

Comment: I know it sounds odd but I'm going to make the jar of jelly beans but also export each jelly bean as a singular model haha.

Comment: ah ok, i update my answer

Comment: Just a little remark. Another way could be defining a set of materials (each with its color) then choose between them for each object. This avoids the creation of one material per objet. But in the context, maybe that does not matter. So +1.

Comment: @lemon: how do i create a set of materials?

Comment: just by bpy.data.materials.new and store that in an array in which you randomly pick. But again, I don't think that matters so much here

Comment: Ideally, what I'm looking to do is create X amount of copies of the active object each with its own random colored material with a for or while loop like my original code.

Its fine if its a lot of objects and a lot of materials because I'm going to batch export the models so I can use them in a jelly bean collecting game.

Comment: @MrP, will they be sugar free?

Comment: Hahaha well played.

Comment: @Chris, reading again the question, one material (one color) per object, so you're good. Eventually, MrP needs object duplication (?)... is that right MrP?

Comment: Yes, duplication + assign new random color material.

Sorry I'm new to stack exchange and also new to blender py

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Thank you Chris, now to go through it and see how far off I was haha.

Something tells me I was fairly far off. But thank you so much for the help

Comment: you are welcome. If my answer helped you, please check the checkmark left to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MrP, don't forget to upvote and accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thats amazing. I accepted the answer. Thank you all again!